# Keys.D1 = LButton | ShiftKey | Space?

Tags: c#, key

A program I've written that normally works well is now freaking out about Keys.D1 having a value of "LButton | ShiftKey | Space"

Here's a screen grab of the problem:
[image]

ModifierKeys is an enum with the following definition:

```
public enum ModifierKeys : uint
{
    Alt = 1,
    Control = 2,
    Shift = 4,
    Win = 8
}
```

What on earth is going on here? There are no other references to Keys.D1.

Comment: Keys.D1 should not equal LButton | ShiftKey | Space - It should be the KeyCode for the Numeral 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx):

> **Caution**
>   Do not use the values in this enumeration for combined bitwise operations. The values in the enumeration are not mutually exclusive.

Although the `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration has the `[Flags]` attribute, the only flags that can actually be safely used as flags are:

- `Keys.Shift`
- `Keys.Ctrl`
- `Keys.Alt`

All the remaining values are not "flags" enumeration values.  As a result, some combinations of values that are not "flags" values coincidentally happen to combine to form other values that are not "flags" values.

The effect your are seeing is the `Enum.ToString()` operator *misusing* the `[Flags]` attribute to construct such combinations.  This is harmless because the `ShiftKey` and the `Space` key are never intended to be combined, per the documentation above.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. Do you have any suggestions on how to hook the Windows key in order to be a global hotkey?