# How to use the DataGridView's Keydown event and check what key was pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this really simple block of code:

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
            AddRow();

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            RemoveRow();
    }
```

Then when I step through my code and hit either `Delete` or `Backspace`, this is the value of e.KeyCode:

[image]

I know my code doesn't check for `Delete` but I can add that in simply afterwards.

If I cast `KeyCode` to a string, it gives me the value "Delete" but I shouldn't have to do that...

edit; I should note that my first block of code, for Ctrl-V works perfectly fine. So I don't understand why e.KeyCode doesn't evaluate to Keys.Delete or Keys.Backspace?

edit 2;
My coworker found something that could be 100% coincidental, or extremely interesting.

`KeyCode.Delete` = 46.
`KeyCode.Space` = 32
`KeyCode.Back` = 8
`KeyCode.MButton` = 4;
`KeyCode.RButton` = 2;

32 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 46.  I feel like some tinfoil hat conspiracy theorist for thinking this might be on to something, but we're completely baffled.

Comment: So what's your question again?

Comment: @davidsbro Why does e.KeyCode evaluate to `RButton | MButton | Back | Space` when I press Delete or Backspace. Sorry, added that to the bottom of my edit.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx), `"This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values"`

What you see is string representation of the enum value. It uses `Flags` attribute to construct the string in `Enum.ToString()` method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747864/keys-d1-lbutton-shiftkey-space) SO question for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`Back` is the enumeration value that indicates the backspace key was pressed ([MSDN-Keys Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Example code:

```
if (e.KeyCode.HasFlag(Keys.Back)) {
   //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: But I'm **only** pressing the Delete Key. Why would it think I'm also pressing MButton, RButton and Space?

Comment: Also, I tried this `HasFlag` call and now it deletes two rows instead of one **and** still evaluates to MButton RButton etc.